# How do I prove that $X = Y$ is equivalent to $(X\cap Y^{c})\cup(X^{c}\cap Y) = \varnothing$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I prove the following equivalence?
\begin{align*}
X = Y \Longleftrightarrow (X\cap Y^{c})\cup(X^{c}\cap Y) = \varnothing
\end{align*}

I am stuck trying to prove this equality. I have already proven that, if $X = Y$, then the other proposition is true, but I cannot seem to find a way to prove it the other way around.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

The union of two sets is empty iff both are empty.